# ValueError at /profile/ ModelForm has no model class specified. Error django

Tags: django, django-forms

Iam coding in django and trying to figure how to update profile of a user in my app
Please help me Iam trying to learn how to code and this is a big barrier for me to learn
here's models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to="profile_pics")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            messages.success(request, f'Yor account has been created! You are now able to login')
            return redirect('/login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html',{'form': form})
@login_required
def profile(request):
    u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance = request.user)
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance= request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

Iam getting error at 'u_form':u_form,

and This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email','password1','password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Profile
    field = ['image']
```

Iam getting my error at this
`p_form = ProfileUpdateForm()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ProfileUpdateForm` you defined the model class name without the `Meta` class

Model name and fields should be defined inside the Meta class like this:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

Comment: Thankyou it works and ` exclude = ['fields'] ` must be included